# session key is not found... not accessible

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, boto3, django-sessions

Got this error that session key is not found in django project:

> File "D:\mysite\source\accounts\views.py", line 31, in      from .storage_loc import UserStorage   File "D:\mysite\source\accounts\storage_loc.py", line 16, in      class UserStorage(S3Boto3Storage):   File "D:\mysite\source\accounts\storage_loc.py", line 18, in UserStorage     use = us.**getitem**('user')
>         File "D:\mysite\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\base.py", line 64, in **getitem**
>           return self._session[key]
>       KeyError: 'user

Storage_loc.py

```
 class UserStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
        us = SessionStore()
        use = us.__getitem__('user')
        location = 'users/%s' % use
        file_overwrite = False
```

forms.py

```
class SignInViaEmailForm(SignIn):
    email = forms.EmailField(label=_('Email'))
    @property
    def field_order(self):
        if settings.USE_REMEMBER_ME:
            return ['email', 'password', 'remember_me']
        return ['email', 'password']
    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user = User.objects.filter(email__iexact=email).first()
        if not user:
            raise ValidationError(_('You entered an invalid email address.'))
        if not user.is_active:
            raise ValidationError(_('This account is not active.'))
        self.user_cache = user
        s = SessionStore()
        s['user'] = email
        s.save()
        return email
```

Comment: For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I think the error is in views.py file and probably you are trying to access a key that does not exist in the dictionary. You should try something like: my_dict.get('user', None) in stead of my_dict['user']